# Can't select individual user accounts when creating a new Asp.Net Core 2.1 Angular project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.1, visual-studio-2019

I just installed VS 2019 and I'm trying to create a new project using Asp.Net Core 2.1 and I then selected Angular. In the right hand side of the window I selected change

[image]

then I tried to select 'Individual User Accounts' but it's grayed out!

[image]

Any help as to why?

This is 2019 Community edition, just released yesterday.

I tried the command

> dotnet new angular --auth Individual

and here is what I see

[image]

I believe I have all the most recent updates, I just installed VS 2019 a few days ago